# connect website compute engine VM using cloud sql as database

Tags: php, sql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine

I'm working on a simple website which consists of student login database using PHP as backend and MySQL as a database. Everything is working fine. Later, I thought to host this on GCP compute engine VM (Linux 18.04) thing and cloud SQL. Can any help me regarding database configuration file to connect to cloud SQL from my VM.

```
<?php
$host = "99.999.999.99";
$user = "root";
$password = "password";
$database = "logindb";
$port = null;
$socket = "/cloudsql/project_id:us-central1:studentlogin"
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $user,$password, $database, $port, $socket)or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: '".mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db ($con,'logindb');
?>
```

And how'd I call the function from another PHP file like..

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to connect to your Cloud SQL instance using a GCE instance, I'll try to explain all of them:

1.Using a `Public IP`. This is maybe the easiest one due to your use case, your `PHP` configuration looks correct (the `$port` parameter should be 3306 btw). To connect to your Cloud SQL instance using Public IP just go [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances?_ga=2.155134256.-960895060.1537888882), select your Cloud SQL instance, go to "Authorized networks", click Add network and enter the IP address of your GCE instance.

2.Using `Private IP`. This is similar to the previous one, but you need to take into account [some considerations](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip#administration_considerations), then, you just need to edit your Cloud SQL instance, activate the Private IP and connect to it from your GCE instance

3.Using `Cloud SQL Proxy`. To use this option, just follow [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy).

4.Using `Client libraries`. But the [Cloud SQL client library for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/libraries#samples) is in beta nowadays, so I recommend you to use some of the options listed above.

Comment: Thanks for replying.I'm trying with your first option from the very beginning, but the problems still persist the same. My index page still not loading. here is what I got from my webpage `This page isn’t working 35.190.138.50 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500` Any help would be thanful.

Comment: I can connect and access my sql enginefrom command line. But things not working from php script.

Comment: The 500 error is expected, due to your Cloud SQL instance is not allowed to serve content using the port 80 (HTTP), so, when you try to access to the Public IP of your Cloud SQL instance it will show you a 500 Error. Regarding the connection from your PHP script, I'm not able to see any issue with your code, which error is showing you? and I understand that you whitelisted the Public IP of your GCE instance into the connections section of your Cloud SQL instance, right?